# Webservice call through proxy server

Tags: java, ssl, proxy, web-services

I need to make a webservice call to a secured link(https:\). It is a two way SSL enabled link. So to access that link for making a webservice call, i need to  set proxy server  to the webservice link .Is there a sample code available for this ?

Comment: WHich webservice library are you using?

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the webservice client you use. If you just use the default client in Java. You just need to setup these parameters,

```
    System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", proxyHost);
    System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", proxyPort);
```

Technically, you can't proxy HTTPS. This is called HTTPS or SSL tunneling. Unlike regular proxy, the proxy server can't inspect the HTTP request.

Comment: It should be noted that this change will affect the entire JVM, not just the current app.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention what language you're working with, but a lot of web service APIs will work happily over SSL -- that is, you don't necessarily need a proxy.  For example, I have some Python code that interact with an XML-RPC API, and this works just fine:

```
s = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('https://www.example.com/rpc/xmlrpc')
```

If you can clarify your question and perhaps provide some examples of what you're trying to do I might be able to provide a better answer.

Comment: he did mention the language in the tags - java

Comment: I'm pretty sure Java's web services libraries will work fine over an https: link, modulo some mucking about with keystores or something.